# Standard error bars don't line up on my line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm plotting a mouse dataset looking at tumor growth volume and exercise. In my plot I'm making I'm using X as age, Y as tumor volume. The mice are grouped by batch and also by genotype. Here is a sample data set:

```
df <- data.frame(mouse = c(1680, 1680, 1680, 1681, 1681, 1681, 
                       1682, 1682, 1682, 1683, 1683, 1683),
             age = c(10, 11, 12, 
                     10, 11, 12,
                     10, 11, 12,
                     10, 11, 12),
             group = c('-/- Wheel Running', '-/- Wheel Running', '-/- Wheel Running',
                       '+/+ Wheel Running', '+/+ Wheel Running', '+/+ Wheel Running',
                       '+/+ Sedentary', '+/+ Sedentary', '+/+ Sedentary', 
                       '-/- Sedentary', '-/- Sedentary', '-/- Sedentary'),
             batch = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
             volume = sample(0:100, 12))
```

First I calculated standard error by using `dplyr` and `plotrix`, see below:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
group_by(group, batch, mouse) %>%
summarize(ste = std.error(volume))
```

Then I merged it with the existing dataset using:

`testmerge <- merge(df, df2, by=c('group', 'batch', 'mouse'))`

I plot it using this code and my error bars are not in line with the lines, they are either above or below the respective line

```
plot1a <- subset(testmerge, batch == "1") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=age, y=volume, color=group)) + 
  stat_summary(aes(group=group), fun=mean, geom="line", size=1.5) +
  theme_classic() +
  ggtitle("batch 1 (n=15)") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=volume - ste, ymax=volume + ste), width=.2)
```

My question I guess is two things

1. Did I calculate standard error correctly? I understand calculating standard error is std/sqrt(n) but I get confused when there are multiple groups such as batch, group, and mouse.
2. If I did calculate standard error correctly, I'm confused as to why my error bars aren't showing up correctly. Is there a piece I'm missing?

Sorry for this being so wordy, I tried to explain with as much detail as I could. Thank you so much!

Comment: OP, what are you getting for your plot?  When I run your code, it looks just fine.  The error bars are centered in the proper location.  Were you expecting something different?

Comment: why would you do filter on batch == 1, and then do a stat_summary? There are only three records for batch == 1, one at each age point, there are no replicates to do the mean/summary on at this point, just draw a plain line through the points

Comment: there aren't multiple groups to color by either

Comment: @Sirius, when I remove the subset parameter and plot entirely with the `testmerge` dataset, it still looks fine to me (and you get all the different groups represented).  OP, please, can you share a picture of your plot and describe what you are seeing that's incorrect?

Comment: Me too, I was irking OP to think through what he was really doing here, or if he was holding info back.